# Add new column to existing database table

Tags: typescript, knex.js, adonis.js

I have created a model and migration using `node ace make:migration user` and `node ace make:model user`, now I want to add another column to the user model.

How do I add another new column after already creating a model and migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the KnexJS documentation about migrations : https://knexjs.org/#Schema-Building

AdonisJS documentation : https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/migrations#alter-example

### How to create new column

#### Create new migration file

```sh
node ace make:migration add_new_column --table=users
```

#### Update code in migration file

```
import BaseSchema from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Schema'

export default class Users extends BaseSchema {
  protected tableName = 'users'

  public async up () {
    this.schema.table(this.tableName, (table) => {
      // Create new column with table.<type>(<name>)
      table.text('my_new_column')
    })
  }

  public async down () {
    this.schema.table(this.tableName, (table) => {
      table.dropColumn('my_new_column')
    })
  }
}
```